# Conditioning reduces variance

Tags: conditional-expectation

I seek to find some $c > 0$ so that $\mathbb{P} \left[ \textrm{var} \left( Y \right) \geq \textrm{var} \left( Y | \, X \right) \right] \geq c$.

Intuitively, it seems clear that conditioning should reduce variance through the interpretation of conditioning as providing information.

By the "law of total probability", we know that $\textrm{var} \left( Y \right) < \mathbb{E} \left[ \textrm{var} (Y | \, X ) \right]$ and $\textrm{var} \left( Y \right) < \textrm{var} \left[ \mathbb{E} (Y | \, X ) \right]$. However, the intuition stated above seems to be for the first statement, not the last two.

Does $c$ exist for arbitrary $(X, Y)$ such that all of these moments exist? If not, under what conditions does such a $c$ exist? Under what conditions does $c=1$?

Comment: See section 5 "Conditional Monte Carlo" of http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/MCS04/MCS_var_red1.pdf .

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no $c$ that works for arbitrary $X$ and $Y$.  Consider this simple case: $Y \sim$ normal$(0, 1)$ if $X = 1$ and $Y = 0$ when $X = 0$, with $X \sim$ Bernoulli$(p)$.  $P[\text{Var}(Y) \geq \text{Var}(Y \mid X)] = 1 - p$, which could be as small as we like.

While I'm sure there are others, one trivial case where $c = 1$ is when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.